# jakarta.servlet.jsp cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I have included the following dependency, but the error keep coming.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So, which dependency I have to add in addition to the above dependency ?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1) Open pom.xml file.

Step 2) Paste the following dependency in the pom.xml file.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Step 4) So, there are now two dependencies.

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>5.0.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>


   <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Step 3) Update the maven project.

Step 4) Problem is solved.